# Remove shipping address from paypal express checkout

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using express checkout in my website. I want to disable shipping address from it while completing the transaction. i am using script on a button. Piece of code that i am using is this.

```
paypal.Button.render({
        env: 'production', // sandbox | production
        client: {
            sandbox:    'mykey',
            production: 'mykey'
        },

        // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
        commit: true,

        // payment() is called when the button is clicked
        payment: function(data, actions) {

            // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
            return actions.payment.create({
                payment: {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: '5.00', currency: 'EUR' }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        },

        // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                window.location = "address";
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');
```

Help will be really appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still looking for a solution the shipment address can be disabled by adding the following lines:

```
experience: {
  input_fields: {
    no_shipping: 1
  }
}
```

So your code needs to be adjusted like this:

```
...
// Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
return actions.payment.create({
  payment: {
    transactions: [
      {
        amount: { total: '5.00', currency: 'EUR' }
      }
    ],
    experience: {
      input_fields: {
        no_shipping: 1
      }
    }
  }
});
...
```